# How to run all tests in a setup.py script?

Tags: python, django, setuptools, django-testing

I would like to write a setup.py script that runs all of my django app's tests and fails the installation if one of the tests don't pass.
How can it be done? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using setuptools, check out [test build package and run a unittest suite](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite) from their docs. which I believe lets you run `setup.py test` and doesn't install your package, but runs the tests in an egg.  From here you can run `setup.py install`. This does seem to be a new command (my version doesn't have it listed).

Comment: This is great but how do I use the django test suite instead?

Comment: @the_drow: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#test-loader  (it's mentioned in the link I posted how to use a different test loader). I've personally never used this method... really is new to me (I originally started writing up a hack till I checked out the docs on some specifics for the hack and ran into this). This is probably something you'll need figure out on your own from here, sorry.